# Error when send POST request to FB via httr

Tags: r, facebook, api, curl, httr

I am working on a request for FB via httr and keep running into the same error.

This is how I am creating the body for the request and convert it to a JSON object using jsonlite library:

```
body <- list()
innerBody <- list()
innerBody$video_id <- videoID
body$canvas_video <- innerBody
body$access_token<-Pagetoken
toJSON(body, pretty = TRUE)
```

All of the fields are required by the request I am trying to make. The output is the following JSON object: (please note I have removed the token for privacy)

```
{
 "canvas_video": {
 "video_id": ["10160728276111111"]
   },
  "access_token":  [<TOKEN>]
}
```

I make the request to facebook via the following call (please note I removed the page ID due to privacy):

```
Test<-POST(url'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/<PAGEID>/canvas_elements',
       body = body,enconde=c("json"))
```

The expected outcome is the following:

```
{
 "id": "1111154434423329"
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error in curl::handle_setform(handle, .list = req$fields) : 
Unsupported value type for form field 'canvas_video'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just one note, because of page permissions I have to set the token via parameters and not via the authenticate function.

(Update) fixed typo in title

(Update 2) after some testing Im almost sure that the issue lies in the nested JSON object

Comment: hmm, what if you try to set body as string and not as json-object?: `Test<-POST(url'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/<PAGEID>/canvas_elements', body = toJSON(body))`

Comment: @JohnnyAW Hey thanks, tried that but now getting another error: "An access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: you could try to add the `access_token` to the url: `graph.facebook.com/v3.1/<PAGEID>/canvas_elements?access_token=abcd`

Comment: Tried it, still getting the error as my last comment =(